# Ajax success function doesn't react on response

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have made a Photo upload system but got a issue now:

Here the Ajax part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#upload").click(function(e){
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../system/avatar_system.php",
                data:formData,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == "upload_ok"){
                        location.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                }
            });
        });
});
```

here the html:

```
<div class="form_box">
        <form id="avatar_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="../system/avatar_system.php">
            <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" name="file" class="select_file">
            <label for="file">Bild auswählen</label>
            <input id="upload" type="submit" value="Bild ändern" class="upload_file">
        </form> 
    </div>
```

and here the avatar_system.php:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
$dirpath = "../users/". $username ."/avataruploads/";
if(!is_dir($dirpath)){
    if(!mkdir($dirpath, 0777, true)){
        $error =  error_get_last();
        echo "Failed creating Folder";
        exit();
    }       
}

$file = $_FILES['file'];

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];

$fileExplode = explode('.', $fileName);
$fileExt = strtolower(end($fileExplode));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
if(in_array($fileExt, $allowed)){
    if($fileError === 0){
        if($fileSize < 32768000){
            $fileNewName = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $fileExt;
            $filepath = $dirpath . $fileNewName;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $filepath);
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET avatar = '$filepath' WHERE username = '$username'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo "upload_ok";
            exit();
        }else{
            echo "This file is to big";
            exit();
        }
    }else{
        echo "There was an Error";
        exit();
    }
}else{
    echo "Not allowed Extension";
    exit();
}
}
```

I want that the site reloads if the response is 'upload_ok', but I get a new blank page with the message 'upload_ok'.
Or maybe it should not reload the page but just change the avatar immediately.

How is this possible?

Comment: Any errors in developers console?

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 ('form') to the FormData constructor must be an instance of HTMLFormElement

Comment: Then replace `new FormData(this);` to `new FormData(this.form);`

Comment: Its working! Can you give a small eyplanation why

Comment: Thank you very much by the way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see in error text

> TypeError: Argument 1 ('form') to the FormData constructor must be an instance of HTMLFormElement

you pass to `FormData` **not** `<form>` but `<input[type=submit]>`.

So, you should pass a `<form>`. The simplest way is

```
var formData = new FormData(this.form);
```

This is possible because `input`s of a `form` always have property `form`, in which there's a `<form>`, that input belongs to.

Comment: Never knew inputs had references to their own forms, very cool!

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
$("#upload").click(
```

to

```
$('#avatar_form').submit(
```

As mentioned by u_mulder this is bound to the button instead of the form. Also it is a good practice to use the submit event instead of button clicks because you can also submit a form but pressing enter in an input field.